# Imploding nested arrays

Tags: php

If I have an array structured like this:

```
$array[index]['first_name']
$array[index]['last_name']
```

Is there an easy way to implode it into something like first_name last_name,first_name last_name, etc. for all the indices?

Implode didn't seem to do what I wanted for something like this. Currently I'm just looping over the whole thing, but it's a SIGNIFICANT bottleneck.

Comment: How is the array getting set up?  It may be more efficient to take care of it then instead of looping through the array later.

Comment: I don't have any control over how the array is set up, it's returned from a website's API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function combineFirstLastName($user) {
    return $user['first_name'] . ' ' . $user['last_name'];
}

$firstLastNames = array_map('combineFirstLastName', $array);
```

If you're using PHP >= 5.3, you can use an anonymous function.

```
$firstLastNames = array_map(function($user) {
    return $user['first_name'] . ' ' . $user['last_name'];
}, $array);
```

I'm not sure you'll get much more of a speed improvement, though.  Have you considered [opcode caching](https://www.php.net/apc)?

Comment: No, I haven't - I'm pretty new to PHP. Looking over the documentation briefly, it looks like you need to install it ahead of time on the server. Is that correct? I don't have root access - my webspace is provided through a hosting provider.

Comment: @Alex Zylman, Check [`phpinfo`](http://us.php.net/phpinfo).  You may have the extensions installed already.

Comment: @strabger, there's a lot of stuff listed in phpinfo and I'm not exactly sure where to look, but I scanned through the whole thing and nothing stood out. I also did a ctrl+f for apc with no luck.